# What is the OBD-II drive cycle for a 2003 Toyota Corolla?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, corolla

[This site](http://www.toyotanation.com/forum/103-3rd-4th-generation-1992-1996-1997-2001/103663-2001-drive-cycle-following-obdii-reset.html) includes a post with the specific drive cycle that resets the OBD-II monitors on several 2000-2002 Toyota vehicles. What does the drive cycle look like for a 2003 Toyota Corolla?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Toyota Service Bulletin

http://www.toyotapart.com/READINESS_MONITOR_DRIVE_PATTERNS_T-EG02-003.pdf